In a C# Console App how do I run a routine before displaying the console window?
In a C# Console App, how do I run a routine before displaying the console window?

Sounds like an XY-Problem. What are you trying to do, exactly? The console hosts your application, not the other way around.

You could hide it (calling SetWindowPos), but, as mentioned, what for? Are you trying to prevent the user from closing it while you're doing something dangerous?

The very first action of a console app is to get a console window - it is its nature of being a console app. But you can design it, not to be a console app and get a console window when needed. Look for console for WinForms/WPF apps

Change the OutputType in csproj file from Exe (with console) to WinExe (without console)

I headed down the win app road, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier way.

The short answer

You can't because the console which your console app runs in exists, and is already visible, before your app starts.

The longer answer

You can control this outside the C# app by controlling how the app is launched, namely make it a GUI app instead.

Answers here work for Net Framework for Windows only, and for dotnet core cross-platform you can use AvaloniaUI or Xamarin.
For example, an Avalonaui app has a static main() method which means you can do stuff, and then not open the GUI window at all. Optionally, you then launch a console with Process.Start().

In a C# Console App, the console window is typically the starting point for your program. So, if you need to do any initial setup or configuration before anything else happens, the best place to put that code is at the very beginning of your Main method. You can use a Thread or a Task to handle this setup in the background. Hope it helps!
